# How could I fix my question

Tags: discussion

I got a Hold for one of my questions. I tried to fix it in order to be reopened. I just wonder if you have any clue on how to reword it to get reopened.

Here is my question:
[How to make more extensive logging on Darwin CalDAV Server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/930877/how-to-make-more-extensive-logging-on-darwin-caldav-server)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question was closed because you twice ask for help finding a product or "hack" that does what you want. That's specifically off topic, as stated in the close reason in your post. So if you want it re-opened, you need to make it clear that you're trying to figure out how to change your configuration rather than looking for a recommendation for an add-on.

Once that's done, there's another thing that really stands out for me: There is very little information about your current setup and configuration. You've told us the name of the application and the version of the operating system, but nothing else. What logs have you looked at? What configuration files or options have you set and to what? Also, you say that you've tried things such as to install git, but you've not told us *how* you were trying to use it or what the outcome of those attempts were.

In short, your question should contain the following information:

- What have you tried?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?
- What does your config look like?
- Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?
- If so, what do they say?

Comment: Thanks, I think you all helped to fix the question. Now awaiting re-open votes if you think its ok.

Comment: @swift_dan There is still very little information about your configuration, your settings, what you actually did when you tried to install git and why/how that didn't work as you wanted, etc.